# Why Frontend Validation is used on Register Form but not on Login Form?

Tags: frontend, backend

I have noticed that sites like facebook, google, upwork uses back-end validation for their login form instead of frontend validation.

Even for basic validation such as checking if the input field is empty or not, they use back-end! Why is so?

I further noticed that they all use **front-end validation only for registration forms**. I don't know if this is a coincidence but I would really like to know what's the reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

as u said Why Frontend Validation is used on Register Form but not on Login Form? yes before going to this i will let you know one thing as you said you have noticed sites like facebook,google,upwork will only use back-end validation.ok its write but they will also use front-end validation.as i will come to the question Mostly the Client Side Validation depends on the JavaScript Language, so if users turn JavaScript off, it can easily bypass and submit dangerous input to the server . So the Client Side Validation can not protect your application from malicious attacks on your server resources and databases.
all use front-end validation only for registration forms because For example, if the user enter an invalid email format, you can show an error message immediately before the user move to the next field, so the user can correct every field before they submit the form.
As both the validation methods have their own significances, it is recommended that the Server side validation is more SECURE!

Comment: This has good and helpful information, but it is very difficult to read. This answer could be improved with some basic formatting (possibly a pro/con list). Additionally, it makes a claim that something is "recommended" without any source. This can also be improved by providing a link/quote to documentation/guidance in support of the recommendation.

Comment: sure buddy i will you know